# search Google Calendar extendedProperties

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I have the following problem when doing a `privateExtendedProperty` search

```
$service = new Google_CalendarService($client);
$extendedProperties = New Google_EventExtendedProperties();

$param = array();
$param['singleEvents'] = false;
$param['extendedProperties'] = "CodeID=66";

$events = $service->events->listEvents($calendarioId,$param);
```

> Fatal error: 
>          Uncaught exception 'Google_Exception' with message '(list) unknown parameter: 'extendedProperties'' in
>   ..\google\service\Google_ServiceResource.php:111 
>       Stack trace: 
>         #0 ...\includes\google\contrib\Google_CalendarService.php(529): Google_ServiceResource->__call('list', Array) 
>         #1 ...\google_calendario.php(198): Google_EventsServiceResource->listEvents('hude3h3fjolua08...', Array) 
>         #2 ..\google_calendario.php(442): c_googlecalendario->proc_google('hude3h3fjolua08...', '66')

Answer (score 1):

With the latest api on [github](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) you can do this:

```
$events = $service->events->listEvents($calendarId, array('privateExtendedProperty'=>'codeID='.$yourId));
```

Pay attention that it's either `privateExtendedProperty` or `sharedExtendedProperty` depending on how you created the event.